# Placement of Secondary Horizontal Axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, axis

On the primary horizontal axis I can go to Format Axis > Line Color and Style. There I can choose the color and style of the line that represents 0 on the primary vertical axis.

However, with the secondary horizontal access, I can format with color and thickness of the line, but it is located at the very top of the chart, and not at the 0 value of the secondary vertical axis. (see image)

[image]

Am I missing a option in the chart controls?

If this really isn't possible, is there a way to draw a line all the way across the chart area (not stopping at the first and last x-axis categories)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the secondary vertical axis, and where it says Horizontal Axis Crosses, choose Automatic, which means at zero. (The default for the secondary axis is Maximum Axis Value.)

Comment: That was it Jon. Didn't think to check the vertical axis properties. Thanks!